# How to make OpenVPN client work on UDP only and a non-default port?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I wanted to configure OpenVPN to run on a non-standard UDP port only, to avoid opening several ports on my router for port forwarding. However, it looks like the OpenVPN client can only connect if I use both TCP and UDP on their default ports (443 and 1194, respectively).

So these are the only settings that work at the moment:

[image]

If I change the protocol, or the ports used, the connection is refused. Looking into the logs, I see entries like these:

```
2015-01-09 17:05:04+0000 [Uninitialized] DynamicClientBase: Unable to obtain Session ID from u'192.168.0.13', port(s)=443: XML-RPC: ConnectionRefusedError: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..:
```

So it looks like the client (OpenVPN Connect on Windows) is trying to use the default ports. How can I make the OpenVPN client work when using UDP only and a different port?

Comment: Why are you even using OpenVPN Connect? That’s not the “real” client. If you want to fully utilize OpenVPN, you need to use the Open Source client.

Comment: Furthermore, did you download a new client like warning indicated?  The new client will have a new built-in configuration file that recognizes the chages you did on the access server.  Your existing client is likely still using the old configuration.

Comment: @DanielB I use it because that's the one created by the server. What open source version of the client are you referring to?

Comment: @ultrasawblade I thought there could be a way to overwrite the config generated by the server, but apparently the correct way to do this is to redownload the client altogether. Please consider turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download a new client like warning indicated? The new client will have a new built-in configuration file that recognizes the changes you did on the access server. Your existing client is likely still using the old configuration.

---

I haven't played with the Access Server too much but there may be a way to "export" the current client configuration file from the server somehow (it'll be an `.ovpn` file) and then publish it or distribute it as you need.  Probably still easier to just redownload/reinstall the client.